# Cannot Open Multiple Word Documents in seperate window

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I can only open one Word document at a time. Every time i open a new document, the previous document automatically replaced. How can be fixed this condition.

Answer (score 0):

The document is not replaced actually. It stays opened. You just need to call the [Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822131(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Document class which activates the specified document so that it becomes the active document. For example:

```
Sub OpenSales() 
 'Sales.doc must exist and be open but not active. 
  Documents("Sales.doc").Activate 
End Sub
```